# Chronoforms shows only link, no elements

Tags: joomla, chronoforms

probably an easy question, but my googling is currently failing me and I'm pretty new to Joomla!, so I might have overseen something obvious.

Using ChronoForms5, when adding a form to a page, the only thing getting displayed is the "Powered by Chrono etc." link, but none of the form elements (only inputs currently) are shown.

This description probably is pretty basic, but I'm not sure what else I would need to include. If somebody had an idea where the problem lies I'd be very thankful.

Edit: As this is not a very advanced question, I posted it here instead of the joomla SE. Just move it over if you think it would fit better over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Setup tab, you need to include a "HTML (Render Form)" action in the "On load" event for the form to be displayed.

There is a fairly comprehensive beginner tutorial / example for ChronoForms v5 at:

http://www.chronoengine.com/chronoforms-start-guide.html

Comment: Used that page, and just completely overlooked it...I'm stupid. Thanks for the heads-up, now it works.